# os x server localhost alternate port not responding

Tags: docpad

Somehow the node.js server used for docpad running on my MacBook (running 10.8.4) are no longer accessible. Docpad (using the default "docpad run") normally publishes on port 9778, and is accessible via localhost:9778 (or 127.0.0.1:9778), and this used to work just fine, and was reliable. Now, however, Safari says 'Safari can't connect to the server "localhost"' ... same thing for Chrome, so it's not a Safari issue.

The one thing that HAS changed, is that now I have OS X Server 2.2 installed ... and the default server webpage does appear at "localhost" or "localhost:80".

Furthermore, another node.js server (the one available with punch), works just fine on any IP number I give it.

Just to make things even more confusing, the docpad server access started to work again last night after a clean install of the twitter-bootstrap skeleton, and then stopped again this AM. I restarted the MacBook ... no change. I turned the web server off using the OS X Server console ... no change.

Something weird with the docpad server code?

Any ideas?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. Try serverfault, perhaps.

Comment: serverfault is not useful for these kinds of questions (it's really a developer platform question) ... the docpad authors specifically said that these kinds of questions should be posted here ... sorry if that's a problem

Comment: then superuser. your problem is more of a server configuration issue, not a programming question.

Comment: Can you upload the `docpad-debug.log` file that is outputted when you run `docpad run -d`, and link it in your question.